# html entity in ActionLink

Tags: razor, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-views

How can I include html entities in ActionLink. e.g. The case of `&raquo;` below.

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Link Text &raquo;", "Index", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning", @role = "button" })</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Url.Action instead

```
<p><a href=@Url.Action("Index") role="button"><span class="btn btn-warning">Link Text &raquo;</span></a></p>
```